# How do you add a button to a TreeView using a HierarchicalDataTemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, treeview

I've got a TreeView that is constructed like this:

```
  //This is for dynamically building a treeview with templates from an XML file
            XmlTextReader xmlReader1 = new XmlTextReader("HierarchicalDataTemplate1.xml");
            HierarchicalDataTemplate hierarchicalDataTemplate1 = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader1) as HierarchicalDataTemplate;
```

And it reads an XML file like this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=SubCategory}">
  <TextBlock FontSize="36" FontFamily="K22 Monastic" Text="{Binding XPath=@CategoryName}" />
  <Button>Add Subordinate Unit</Button>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

But it throws a runtime error on adding the button:
''Template' property has already been set on 'HierarchicalDataTemplate'.' Line number '3' and line position '4'.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? If I take out the script for adding a button everything works fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious error is that you've got two elements at the root level of the template's visual tree. You can't do that. A `DataTemplate` or `HierarchicalDataTemplate` can have only one child. So your first step is to make that one child a control that supports multiple children of its own, then put your `TextBlock` and your `Button` in that. `StackPanel` is a good one:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=SubCategory}"
    >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock 
            FontSize="36" 
            FontFamily="K22 Monastic" 
            Text="{Binding XPath=@CategoryName}" 
            />
        <Button>Add Subordinate Unit</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

It's interesting to note that when I paste your template XAML into the XAML designer, I get a different error: "The property 'VisualTree' is set more than once" -- but when I duplicate your `XamlReader.Load()`, code, I get the same exception and message as you (and the same fix corrects it).

Google turns up zero results for "Template property has already been set on HierarchicalDataTemplate". Well, maybe it'll have one now.

Comment: This works and doesn't throw an error! Thanks! I can't mark it as the answer for 4 minutes and I have to run out. I'll do it when I get back. Thanks again!

Comment: @zetar Glad to hear it!